# Make a NestJS route send in response a pretty formatted JSON

Tags: json, nestjs

I have a NestJS route which sends back in response, a JSON not well formatted (like minified),
I want to make this JSON easier to read, like a JSON prettier or JSON formatted,
Do someone knows how to do it in NestJS ? I accept answers for other NodeJS frameworks like Express, maybe it will work in NestJS too...

Answer (score 3):

Prettifying the JSON response should be the responsibility of the client, not the server. Otherwise you could be sending a lot of white space which will bloat the response size and could lead to a crash due to having a response too large. If you are using something like Postman, it should be easy to prettify it, I think Postman might do it by default. If you are looking at the response in some web browser, you could use `JSON.parse()` on the response and it should make the response an actual JSON which `console.log()` would then print in a pretty way.

Comment: ok because i'm reading my route response directly on the browser, and it's minified, so I always have to use an online JSON formatter... thank you for your answer

Comment: There exists gzip for something. The usability improvement for the user that doesn't prettify the json is usually better than the few bytes spared i ncase the response is compressed

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

```
// src/main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().set('json spaces', 2);
  }
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you shouldn't do it in prod as mentioned above, there's number of cases where it makes a lot of sense (e.g. in dev env). You can achieve this in a bit hacky way:

1. Access `express` instance inside nest through breaking abstraction. It's not exposed on `INest` interface, so you'll need to cast it to `any` type to bypass Typescript check
2. Set undocumented `express` property `"json spaces"`, which will set formatting for all JSON responses over the app

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  (app as any).httpAdapter.instance.set('json spaces', 2);
}
await app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Define return type `string` on your controller
- Set the `Content-Type: application/json` response header
- Use `JSON.stringify` to format your object with whitespace

Example controller code:

```
import { Controller, Get, Header } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('diagnostics')
export class DiagnosticsController {
  @Get()
  @Header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  findAll(): string {
    const statusCode = 200;
    const statusText = 'OK';

    const info = {
      self: 'NestJS Diagnostics Report',
      status: {
        statusCode,
        statusText,
      },
    };

    return JSON.stringify(info, null, 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try https://www.postman.com or https://insomnia.rest/. It can save you a lot of time when it comes to testing an API.